# get the value and id of select drop down simultaneously in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select drop down from which the id is coming but I want both the id and value of the drop down item I selected.
**My select drop down is this.**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="type">Type</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="type">
       <option>select product type</option>
        <?php 
       $query = "SELECT * FROM item_types";
       $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['type_id']?>"><?php echo $row['type_title']?></option>
       <?php    
        }     
       ?>
   </select>
  </div>
```

I have two tables in my database. The id is coming from other table. I want the product type name also in my second table. I have columns in [database table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYqKE.png) [database table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrWAs.png). It only storing id's but not the type. this is the query for inserting data in table 2.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO item_master(type, item_title, pur_rate, sale_rate, qty) 
           VALUES ('$type', '$title', '$purchaserate', '$salerate', '$qty')";
```

so please help me.

Comment: your code is not safe and is exposed to SQL injection. You should use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: You should only store the `id` and `type` text in one table and just the `id` in other tables.  You can join on `id` when you want the text.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit dirty solution. I recommend you to analyze and find better way doing this. 
Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="type">Type</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="type">
       <option>select product type</option>
        <?php 
       $query = "SELECT * FROM item_types";
       $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $value = $row['type_id'] . '|' . $row['type_title'];
        ?>
       <option value="<?= $value ?>"><?= $row['type_title']?></option>
       <?php    
        }     
       ?>
   </select>
  </div>
```

DB insert PHP chunk:

```
$value = explode('|', $value);
$type = $value[0]; // sanitize input to prevent SQL injection
$title = $value[1]; // sanitize input to prevent SQL injection
$query = "INSERT INTO item_master(type, item_title, pur_rate, sale_rate, qty) 
           VALUES ('$type', '$title', '$purchaserate', '$salerate', '$qty')";
```

Please try to learn basic MVC principles and SQL injection prevention in order to write better and more secure code.